# How to reset thumbnails in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, thumbnails, thumbs.db

I changed the album art of an audio file inside a folder using a id3 tag editor. But the folder thumbnail still shows the old album art.

I tried to clear thumbnail cache using system cleanup, But i see no option for clear **thumbnail cache in system clean-up**.

Also I could not find the `thumbs.db` file in the directory.

How can I reset the thumbnail to show the latest art as folder thumbnail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the below method to reset thumbnails.

```
cd Music
attrib -S -H thumbs.db /S
attrib -S -H AlbumArtSmall.jpg /S
attrib -S -H Folder.jpg /S
del /S AlbumArtSmall.jpg
del /S thumbs.db
del /S Folder.jpg
```

This script will delete the `Folder.jpg` and `AlbumArtSmall.jpg` files from all sub-folders.